# How can I force the NVIDIA display to show up on the HDTV as default like I use to?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, external-display

How can I force the Nvidia display to show up on the HDTV as default like I use to?

#### Details:

I have an Acer laptop with a broken screen. I removed the screen completely and set it to load up the HDTV as the default display, I did this by hooking up an old monitor that it recognized by default and changing the options with it. It has been working fine for over a year now....

One day... I went to switch on my laptop, everything went normal, got the Windows login screen, then it actually went to load the desktop (after the actual loading please wait screen), and then it goes black.

#### What I've Done:

I tried completely un-installing the NVIDIA drivers and re-installing making sure to check the clean install. Prior to this I tried to hook up the old monitor again and got treated with the same results. I've tried having them both hooked up at the same time.

I've tried murdering my registry manually and with CCleaner, Removed anything NVIDIA from my PC, including in AppData, system directories etc.. I've looked in almost every folder for traces of stuff from NVIDIA.

Nothing has worked. I tried using the Windows Update version of the driver. So many things I've tried. Been going at this for days now. Usually I can figure this stuff out or magically get it to work.. not this time..

The only way I can get into Windows is either keep the driver un-installed or just disable it in device manager.

Also, it's not the actual card. Again, it gets to the welcome screen / login screens fine and you can tell the NVIDIA driver has been loaded as things look pretty again.

Is there an ini file I can do this with or something?

Comment: Is the issue that you can't get to the Nvidia control panel to set your options, or that you can't get them to stick?

Are there Function keys that you can use to toggle between LCD and external display?

Comment: I should of mentioned I'm using windows 7. Also, while the Nvidia driver is disabeld you can't access the nvidia control panel =(, I tried looking for some type of ini file or something where settings could be stored with no luck. my actual laptop keyboard doesn't work, I actually have it disconnected (my laptop is basically set up like a PC, only one USB slot is left good so I have to use the logictech wireless set up) so I can't use the actual laptops function keys. The screen and the keyboard went out in the same incident, long story heh... I'm not aware of any windows shortcuts to do it.

Comment: So right now, the VGA screen also goes blank after login with the nVidia card enabled? If so, do you have access to another computer to remote desktop into your laptop and change settings that way?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually have another PC I could use, but I was able to use Android! First, I tried team viewer. It was weird, it'd work at the login screen, but after the blackness hit, it wouldn't allow me to connect anymore, this started to worry me.

Next, I tried LogMein, (Also a big thanks to them!), Worked like a charm.

However, everything isn't settled yet. What is weird with LogMeIn, not sure if it's because I just started using it even at the login screen or what, but when I did log in with logmein, the screen never went black, it just booted up like normal.

I found that kind of odd considering all the hoops I've been jumping through. I wonder what magic code LogMeIn has hidden within its software to make it just work.